# Find (if there exist) a primitive root $\bmod 8.$

Tags: number-theory, primitive-roots

**Recall.**

- Definition $1$. $Ord_n(a)$ is the smallest number $m$ st. $\quad a^{m} \equiv 1(\bmod n)$
- Definition $2$. We say $r$ is a primitive root modulo $n$ if $\operatorname{Ord}_{n} (r)=\phi(n)$
- Note: $\left\{1,r, r^2,..., r^{\phi(n)-1}\right\}=U_n$

> Find (if there exist) a primitive root $\bmod 8.$

I couldn't find a primitive root, how can I show there isn't any primitive root mod 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** If you assume by contradiction that $r$ is a primitive roots, then $r$ is odd 
and hence 
$$r^2-1=(r-1)(r+1)$$
is the product of two consecutive even integers. One of those is divisible by $4$ and the other one is even, thus
$$r^2-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$$